# How to find the kernel of a set function

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following adjacency matrix, I've obtained the set function $f_1 = \{(1,3), (2,2), (3,3), (4,2), (5,2)\}$ (among the others).

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 &  0& 1\\ 
0&  1&  0&  0&0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &1  &1  &0  &0 \\ 
0 & 1 &0  &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

My textbook reports that the quotient set is $\mathrm{X} / \ker\left(\mathrm{f}_1\right) = \{\{1,3\},\{2,4,5\}\}$, however "a quotient set is a set derived from another by an equivalence relation".

From my understanding $\ker$ is defined as $\ker f := \{(x,x')|f(x)=f(x')\}$, but I've trouble finding the ker set, since $\{\ldots(1,3),(3,1)\ldots\}$ does not really makes sense to me (I'm probably missing something here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give the set-theoretic definition of a kernel (note that your question is tagged linear algebra in which there is a different thing also called kernel). More precisely stated, let $X$ and $Y$ be sets and let $f \colon X \to Y$ be some function. Then $\ker f$ is an equivalence relation with
$$ \ker f = \{ (x, y) \in X \times X \mid f(x) = f(y) \},$$
so two elements of $X$ are equivalent under $\ker f$ if they are mapped by $f$ to the same element of $Y$.

If we have an equivalence relation $R$ on some set $X$, we can define the quotient set $X/R$ as a set of so-called *equivalence classes*, that is, each element of the quotient set $X/R$ represents a subset of $X$ whose elements are all equivalent under $R$.

Using the set $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and the equivalence relation $\ker f$, we find that
$1 \equiv 3, 2 \equiv 4 \equiv 5$
as $f(1) = 3 = f(3)$ and $f(2) = f(4) = f(5) = 2$.
Hence, the quotient set $X/\ker f$ is given by $\{[1], [2]\}$ where $[1]$ is the equivalence class of $1$ and $3$ while $[2]$ is the equivalence class of $2, 4$ and $5$. If you, alternatively, denote the equivalence classes as the sets of equivalent elements, you get the answer you specified.